# NSURL going wrong

Tags: objective-c, url, afnetworking, afhttpclient

I have URL like this for example:

```
http://somedomain.com/mi3/marketInfoData?request=login&user=user&password=password
```

but why URL string not same with that I want... it return

```
http://somedomain.com/mi3/marketInfoData/?request=login&user=user&password=pass
```

here my NSurl request

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somedomain.com/mi3/marketInfoData?request=login&user=user&password=pass"]];
```

Error:

```
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest http://somedomain.com/mi3/marketInfoData/?request=login&user=user&password=pass <--error
```

and I got an error like this because it has "/" before "?" How do I escape it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Also important to note is that a trailing slash will be added to any
>   `baseURL` without one, which would otherwise cause unexpected behavior
>   when constructing URLs using paths without a leading slash.

Try this pattern:

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somedomain.com/mi3/"]];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"request": @"login", @"user" : @"user", @"password" : @"pass"};

[httpClient getPath:@"marketInfoData" parameters:params success:nil failure:nil];
```

Obviously, you don't really want to use `nil` success and failure blocks.

You should typically create one AFHTTPClient for each API you're hitting (most apps only have one.)  Creating a new AFHTTPClient for each request is an error.

Comment: hmm i switchback to ios nsurlconnection :)